# why the tensorflow's weights don't change sometimes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to try to solve a Dichotomous problem that `x1 + x2 < 1`.
There's a problem is that sometimes the weights of net don't change.But sometimes it works correctly. This is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,2),name = 'input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,2),name='output')
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,4],0.0,0.2))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,4],0.0,0.2))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,2],0.0,0.2))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,2],0.0,0.2))
a = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x_,w1)+b1)
y = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(a,w2)+b2)
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y,1e-10,1.0)))
op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
tra = op.minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    aa = np.random.rand(100,2)
    bb = np.random.rand(100,2)
    for i in range(100):
        t = int(aa[i][0]+aa[i][1]<1.0)
        bb[i][t] = 1.0
        bb[i][t^1] = 0.0
    print(sess.run(w1))
    for i in range(50000):
        f = random.randint(0,10)
        ae = aa[f*10:(f+1)*10]
        be = bb[f*10:(f+1)*10]
        sess.run(tra,feed_dict={x_:ae,y_:be})
        if i%1000 == 999:
            print(sess.run(w1))
            e = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x_:aa,y_:bb})
            print(e)
```

The loss sometimes is a big float and does't change. I try to change the way of initialize but it does't work. I even don't know how to find where's 
the problem.

Comment: Is it because you are optimising using `ae` & `be`, but printing your loss using `aa` & `bb`?

Comment: I used aa & bb first.The problem happens.Then I thought the problem is the size of train batch is too big.So I use ae &  be.However, the problem also exists.